# Does Wininet handle the HTTP header value "Set-Cookie"?

Tags: winapi, cookies, http-headers, wininet

I have a custom http component that uses Wininet to handle http POST and GET. It works fine, but some sites return a `Set-Cookie` param in the response header and they expect this cookie to be used by the browser on next calls. As far as I can see, my wininet based component is not handling those cookies. I can see it when I use some http sniffers like Http Analyzer. IE works ok. Theres nothing different in my request header, it is the same that IE creates.

Should I take care of those cookies myself? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinInet does not handle cookies.  You need to handle it yourself.

In the WinInet libarary you'll find [`InternetGetCookie()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`InternetSetCookie()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There's a good MSDN article on [Managing Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Specifics will depend on your application and it's architecture, but I usually find implementations using `InternetGetCookie()` clunky.  Instead I'll retrieve all the HTTP headers in-line with the calls to `InternetReadFile()` then call `InternetSetCookie()` if a cookie exists:

```
// Create a session cookie.
bReturn = InternetSetCookie(TEXT("http://www.adventure_works.com"), NULL,
            TEXT("TestData = Test"));
```

MSDN articles with examples for retrieving HTTP headers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385373%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: How should I find what host I need to set the cookie to? I mean, if I post data to http://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxxx.dll?xxx=xxx, should i set the cookie to the host http://www.xxx.com? And if the next request was made to a the same url, but to a https page?

Comment: yes, cookies are explicitly reserved the the domain that returned the set-cookie header.   try reading through the cookie RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt

Comment: Well, that wont work for me. The cookie is like "https://seguro.tjrj.jus.br/segweb/faces/login.jsp?indGet=true&SIGLASISTEMA=PORTALSERV'". Theres not information in the cookie where it came from, but I have the url. In that case should I use `InternetCrackUrl` and set the cookie to the host?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is wrong. CInternetSession does indeed handle cookies. If an http response under this session 
returns a Set-Cookie header the cookie therein will automatically be saved by the session object and returned
to the server on subsequent requests. No need to use SetCookie().

There are a few caveats and pitfalls though: Cookies returned without an expiration date are session cookies 
and are only saved in MEMORY. When the CInternetSession object is destroyed they disappear for ever.

It is possible to set flags in the CInternetSession object with SetOption and on requests which disable cookies.
See the flags INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_SERVER_AUTH and INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES. Take care so you haven't done this.

Beware of CACHING. GET a script once to get the cookie, then GET it again to print the returned cookie. 
And it doesn't work! No cookie is printed. Why? Because the "file" is cached. On the second call wininet doesn't
contact the server, it gives you the old response once again, which of course hasn't printed any cookie. To avoid
this you must use the flag INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD. Here's the essence:

```
int flags = INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;
int port = INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
CHttpConnection *connection = session.GetHttpConnection("www.example.com", flags, port);
CHttpFile *fil = connection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, "cgi-bin/test.pl",
                                         0,1,0, "HTTP/1.1", flags);
fil->SendRequest();
```

Also, note that if the cookie is set by a script with URL http: //example.com/cgi-bin/test.pl it's associated with the URL http: //example.com/cgi-bin/ so will be returned to the script http: //example.com/cgi-bin/hello.pl . The cookie header can change this behaviour though.

Comment: You do realize that is a 2 years old question right? things may have changed so far.

Comment: It has always been like this, as far as I know. At least it was at the time the question was asked and today.

Comment: Yes but its worth noting that this answer only applies to the MFC API, the question only mentions WinINet, not MFC.